# Finding the remainder when a large number is divided by 13

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let a number $x = 135792468135792468$. Find the remainder when $x$ is divided by $13$.

Is it possible to use Fermat's little theorem on this? I notice that the number is also repeating after $8$.

Would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: "$135792468$ $135792468$" is two numbers!!!

Comment: @barakmanos it's one? There shouldn't be a space in between tho

Comment: @barakmanos I have to show the working!

Comment: The intent is likely to solve by some variant of "divisible by 100..001", but long division (or synthetic division) solves this problem. There's no reason to make things more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$135-792+468-135+792-468=0\implies$

- $7$ divides $135792468135792468$ without remainder
- $11$ divides $135792468135792468$ without remainder
- $13$ divides $135792468135792468$ without remainder

This trick is applicable since each one of them divides $1001$ without remainder.

Comment: As a software dev with a passing interest in mathematics Yves' answer is immediately obvious to me, but I'm unclear about yours. It seems to follow some externally proven rule that I'm unaware of. Would you care to elaborate or at least link me to where I can investigate this rule myself?

Comment: @DarrenH: You can prove this by induction. The base cases are a $6$-digit number $\overline{abcdef}$ and a $9$-digit number $\overline{abcdefghi}$ (see following comments).

Comment: $\color\red{\overline{abc}-\overline{def} = 0 \implies \overline{abc} = \overline{def} \implies \overline{abcdef} = 1000\overline{abc}+\overline{def} = 1000\overline{abc}+\overline{abc} = 1001\overline{abc} = 13\cdot77\overline{abc}}$

Comment: $\color\green{\overline{abc}-\overline{def}+\overline{ghi} = 0 \implies \overline{abc}+\overline{ghi} = \overline{def} \implies \overline{abcdefghi} = 1000000\overline{abc}+1000\overline{def}+\overline{ghi} = 1000000\overline{abc}+1000\overline{abc}+1000\overline{ghi}+\overline{ghi} = 1001000\overline{abc}+1001\overline{ghi} = 13\cdot(77000\overline{abc}+77\overline{ghi})}$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now and is a lot simpler than I expected! +1

Comment: Another way to see how it might be true is to see you can write the original number as sums of multiples of 1001.
135−792+468−135+792−468=0

Comment: So you can write the pieces of the original number (135, 792, 468, 135, 792, 468) by splitting into identical numbers. 135, (135+657), (657 -189), (-189+ 324), (324 +468), 468

Answer (score 26):

Brute force isn't demanding so much effort, actually a handful of two-digits subtractions, using the table $13,26,39,52,65,78,91,104,117$.

$$\color{blue}{13}5792468135792468\\\color{blue}{57}92468135792468\\\color{blue}{59}2468135792468\\\color{blue}{72}468135792468\\\color{blue}{74}68135792468\\\color{blue}{96}8135792468\\\color{blue}{58}135792468\\\color{blue}{61}35792468\\\color{blue}{93}5792468\\\color{blue}{25}792468\\\color{blue}{127}92468\\\color{blue}{109}2468\\\color{blue}{52}468\\\color{blue}{46}8\\\color{blue}{78}\\\color{blue}0.$$

Comment: +1 because this is an approach which someone with no knowedge of divisibility tests can come up with.

Comment: +1 as well because this approach is generally applicable. A bag of tricks that only work in rare cases isn't very useful. Take the question, replace 13 with 17, and see which answer still applies.

Comment: @gna This is *equivalent* to using the division algorithm to divide by $13$ (while ignoring quotients). Yes, it will always work, but it will be *much* more work for numbers that have special form, such as the OP's $\,n(\color{#c00}{10^9+1}).\,$  Here the modular approach is much, much simpler, namely $$\,\ {\rm mod}\ 13\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{10^{\large 9}}\equiv ((-3)^{\large 3})^{\large 3}\equiv (-1)^{\large 3}\equiv\,\color{#c00}{-1}$$

Comment: @Yves But there are no "properties of the divisor" to find. Rather we need only compute  $\,\color{#c00}{10^{\Large 9}\bmod 13}\,$ which is simple and *fast* (even if done non-optimally by brute force). Taking advantage of innate power structure will almost always give major speedups over long division in problems like this.

Comment: That said, I do often recommend the same sort of modular-based *universal divisibility test* when such structure is lacking ,e,g. see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/52815/242)

Comment: @Yves  Indeed, I already said that the method exploits the innate structure. But learning how to recognize and exploit innate structure is *essential* to mastering mathematics. In particular, exploiting repeating structure and orders of elements (or, more generally, innate *group / monoid* structure) is *ubiquitous* in number theory.. One cannot go very far without being proficient at such.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I agree with you that it is important to learn the patterns and special forms and even more important to discover *new* patterns, but it is nonetheless very *useful* to have a basic starting point of understanding the *simple* brute force method.  I'm glad this answer was written; I'm also very glad it's not the only answer that was written.

Comment: @Wildcard To be sure, I agree that this method is useful when special structure is lacking. Indeed, as I said above, I often recommend essentially the same method (including same color highlighting!) as a [universal divisibility test.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/52815/242). I too am glad it was posted, since such ideas deserve to be much better known - as do many of the beautiful simplifications made possible via modular viewpoints. A large number  of my posts are devoted to attempting to reveal such beauty in elementary number theory.

Answer (score 10):

A little digression to speculate on the source of the problem.

The test for divisibility by $9$ is well known: the remainder is the sum of the digits (mod $9$).

The test for divisibility by $11$ is a little less well known: look at the alternating sum of the digits. That works because odd powers of $10$ are $-1 \pmod{11}$ while even powers are $1$.

Now note the lovely fact that $7 \times 11 \times 13 = 1001$. That means you can find the remainder mod $1001$ and hence mod $7$, $11$ and $13$ by alternately adding and subtracting "digits" in groups of three - essentially thinking of the number as written in base $1000$.

(Written while @Barakmanos was posting essentially the same argument.)

Answer (score 8):

You noticed how the number repeats, so you can see that it equals $135792468\times1000000001$. Now test $1000000001$ for [divisibility by $13$](http://www.savory.de/maths1.htm) (repeatedly add $4$ times the rightmost digit to the rest of the number, and if you reach a multiple of $13$ (you reach 26 in this case), the original number is divisible by $13$.

[image]

Comment: Note the second factor is $10^9+1$. If you know by heart the handy fact that $13$ divides $1001=10^3+1$ (as do $7$ and $11$, and as remarked elsewhere) then you see $10^3\equiv{-}1\pmod{13}$ and so $10^9+1\equiv(-1)^3+1=0\pmod{13}$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\ 13\mid \overbrace{n\,10^{\large 9}\!+n}^{\textstyle n(\color{#c00}{10^{\large 9}\!+1})\!\!}\,\ $  by $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 13\!:\, \overbrace{\color{#c00}{10^{\large 9}}\equiv ((-3)^{\large 3})^{\large 3}}^{\Large (10\ \ \,\equiv\,\ \ -3)^{\LARGE 9}\quad\ \, }\!\!\equiv (-1)^{\large 3}\equiv\,\color{#c00}{{-}1}$

---

**Remark** $\ \ 7,11,19\mid 10^{\large 9}\!+1$ all follow similarly

$\qquad \left.\begin{align}
{\rm mod}\ \ 7\!:&\,\ \color{#c00}{10^{\large 3}}\ \equiv\,\ 3^{\large 3}\,\ \equiv\,\ \color{#c00}{{-}1}\\ \\
{\rm mod}\ 11\!:&\,\ \color{#c00}{10^{\large 3}}\equiv (-1)^{\large 3}\equiv\color{#c00}{-1}
\end{align}\right\}\ \Rightarrow\, 10^{\large 9}\equiv (\color{#c00}{10^{\large 3}})^{\large 3}\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^3\equiv -1$

$\qquad {\rm mod}\ 19\!:\ 10^{\large 9}\equiv (-3^{\large 2})^{\large 9}\equiv -3^{\large 18}\equiv -1\ $ by little Fermat

The above shows that $\, 7,11,13\mid 10^{\large 3}+1\mid 10^{9}+1\,$ which leads to the well-known divisibility test: *casting out* $1001$'s, i.e. the remainder $\bmod 1001\! =\! \color{#c00}{10^{\large 3}}$ is the alternating digit sum in radix $10^3,\,$ which is the analog of [casting out $11 =$ elevens in radix $10$ (decimal),](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) i.e.

$\begin{align} \bmod 1001\!:\ \ \ \  &\cdots\, d_8 d_7 d_6\,,\, d_5 d_4 d_3\,,\, d_2 d_1 d_0\ \ \text{in radix $\,10^{\large 3}$}\\ \equiv\, &\cdots\,  d_8 d_7 d_6\! \color{#c00}{-\! d_5 d_4 d_3}\!\! +\! d_2 d_1 d_0\end{align}  $

Comment: +1 for an excellent method of solving problems like this, but honestly, your answer would IMO be a lot more readable of you added a few more English words and simplified the notation a bit. As it is, your answer looks kind of like something scribbled on a blackboard during a lecture -- which would be fine on a blackboard, but here on SE people can't hear you explain your thinking as you're writing, so a little more written explanation can be helpful.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen One of the goals of my posts here is to teach readers how to think like an algebraist or number theorist. As such, I purposely avoid spurious human language when it obfuscates the essence of the matter. The sooner students learn to wean themselves from the crutches of natural language, the sooner they will be able to concentrate on the *mathematical* essence of the matter.