# Pattern in the universal divisibility test

Tags: divisibility

**I recently came across this test [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52815)**

I understand how this works but I noticed something in the example given in said answer for the mod 7 of 43211 (I would assume this pattern extends to all other numbers).

(when 43211 is being simplified to 1211)
43000 ≡ 1000 (mod 700)

**Subsequently,**

(when 1211 is being simplified to 511)
1200 ≡ 500 (mod 70)

**Again,**

(when 511 is being simplified to 21)
510 ≡ 20 (mod 7)

I can see why this pattern would arise considering how the method was proved in the first place (using radix [being 10] polynomials in the nested Horner form) but a more mathematical reason or intuition would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Being congruent mod $700$ or $70$ implies being congruent mod $7$.

Comment: yeah I understand that but I was wondering weather it had anything to do with the position of the digit in the number